# Retrieving image from database in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

This is my servlet named **showimage.java**

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();         

        try{            
        Tab person = (Tab) session.get(Tab.class,new Integer(1));     
        byte[] photoBytes = person.getEImage();        
        try (ServletOutputStream sos = res.getOutputStream()) {
             sos.write(photoBytes);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        a++;
        }        
}
```

And below is my jsp page named **showimage.jsp**.I'm getting same images from database in image colomn due to this     **Tab person = (Tab) session.get(Tab.class,new Integer(1));**. Can someone suggest to replace **new Integer(1)** so that every time the servlet is called , i am able to get new Id 
 from database dynamically.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP List Users Records</title>
</head>
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource
        var="myDS"
        driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project"
        user="root" password="lovemapa!23"
    />

    <sql:query var="listUsers"   dataSource="${myDS}">
        SELECT * FROM tab;
    </sql:query>

    <div align="left">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.E_id}" /></td>
                   <td><img src="showimage?id=${user.E_id}"></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass an id as URL parameter: `showimage?id=${user.E_id}`.
In your servlet you can retrieve this value as

```
Integer id = new Integer(req.getParameter("id"));
Tab person = (Tab) session.get(Tab.class, id);
```

Comment: one more doubt Sir, this "id" in showimage?id=${user.E_id} ... is this pre written or we have to  define it? and how do I pass id in URL parameter ,Sir

Comment: Thank You very much Sir, That was really Useful . Thanks a ton :) God bless u :)